# Does the integral exist?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does the integral

$\int^t_{t_0} \frac{(x(t_0)-x(\tau))^2}{(t- \tau)^ \alpha} d \tau$

exist ?

I tried to do like this

$\int^t_{t_0} \frac{(x(t_0)-x(\tau))^2}{(t- \tau)^ \alpha} d \tau = x^2(t_0) \frac{(t-\tau)^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1} -2x(t_0)\int^t_{t_0} \frac{x(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^\alpha}d\tau+ \int^t_{t_0} \frac{x^2(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^\alpha}d\tau$ .

What should I do about the two term of $x(\tau)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The question of existence doesn't ask for the value.
If $\alpha$ is too big, the function will look like $c/(t-\tau)$ or bigger, and the integral will be infinite.
The question of 'too big' depends on whether $x(t_0)=x(t)$, and how many of the derivatives $x'(t),x''(t)$, etc are zero.
Think of a Taylor series for $x(\tau)$ around $\tau=t$.